# SQL PIVOT-WINDOW FUNCTIONS

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, window-functions

With the sql query I get `table 1`

```
with t as(QUERY)
select Date, key, Type,
row_number ( ) over(partition by key order by Date  asc) orders
from t
```

**table 1**

```
Date       Key  Type    orders
12/10/2007  7   Q1      1
30/06/2015  7   W       2
21/06/2019  7   G1      3
31/01/2008  9   Q5      1
5/02/2016   9   W3      2
17/12/2019  9   G2      3
12/10/2007  10  Q12     1
5/02/2016   10  W4      2
17/12/2019  10  G6      3
```

Trying to pivot using window functions below on Server 2012 fails

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select * from crosstab ($$
with t as(QUERY)
select Date, key, Type,
row_number ( ) over(partition by key order by Date  asc) :: integer as orders
from t
$$) as ct (key varchar
                  "1" integer,
                  "2" integer,
                  "3" integer)
order by key asc
```

My desired output

```
    1   2   3
7   Q1  W   G1
9   Q5  W3  G2
10  Q12 W4  G6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select key, 
       max(case when order=1 then type end) as '1',
       max(case when order=2 then type end) as '2',
       max(case when order=3 then type end) as '3'
from tablename
group by key
```

Also, you can try with pivot -

```
SELECT key, piv.* FROM   
(
    select Date, key, Type,
       row_number ( ) over(partition by key order by Date  asc) orders
       from t
) X
PIVOT(
    max(type ) 
    FOR orders IN (
        [1], [2], [3] 
        )
) AS piv
```

Comment: Thanks, know how to get it as you have. My question is why the window function I have tried to use fails

Comment: @wwnde, what is your dbms name

Comment: what do you mean? SQL Server2012

Comment: @wwnde, SQL server does not support crosstab, it has pivot and unpivot operator for doing this

Comment: @wwnde, I've added it - you can check